# Arquitetura de aplicação PHP instalável

Tags: php, linux, deploy, instalador

Estou tentando melhorar minhas aplicações PHP. Neste objetivo gostaria de criar um instalador para uma aplicação web, um site por exemplo.

Já conheço pacotes linux como rpm e deb, não é disso que estou falando, pois alguns servidores não tem acesso ao bash ou a comandos como **exec**, **shell_exec** e **eval**.

Meu intuito é criar uma aplicação **auto-instalável** como um wordpress por exemplo - um pacote para baixar e em um clique instalar.
Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Um pouco ampla a sua pergunta, tem como deixar específica? Algum ponto em particular está  te causando problemas na criação do instalador?

Comment: Você citou wordpress, sua instalação na verdade nada mais é do que a criação de todas as tabelas que ele utiliza no banco de dados, ou seja, não é uma "instalação" exatamente igual aquilo que você me parece estar pedindo...

Comment: Você está falando de scripts de auto-instalação, ou você está falando da magia do auto-update?

Answer (score 14):

O que você poderia fazer é aprender com os exemplos que você citou.
O que o Wordpress faz, assim como outras aplicações PHP (phpMyAdmin, Joomla, Drupal...), é colocar num .ZIP (ou .tar.gz) todos os arquivos que estariam na raiz do site.
Basicamente, você vai na pasta WWW (public_html) do seu projeto e zipar.

Mas ai você quer que o projeto se auto-instale...
A abordagem do wordpress é a mais legal.
Você cria um arquivo `install.php` ou uma rota, que basicamente faz `if/else`, no seguinte fluxo:

- O arquivo de configuração do banco de dados está ok?
- Consigo conectar no banco?
- Existe a tabela whathever no meu banco?

Ai, se você conseguiu conectar legal mas uma tabela chave do banco não existe, você executa os seus comandos SQL que criam o seu banco de dados.

Comment: Acredito que esse passo a passo seja legal e se refere também ao auto-update. Mas como ele se acha em versões alterações de banco de dados e arquivos? Digamos que a versão 1.3 adicionou uma tabela e 10 arquivos?

Comment: Isso chama-se "migration".
O que você pode fazer é criar uma tabela que controla versões e o script update.php (exemplo) que verifica essa tabela e executa SQLs de create, alter e drop tables.
Frameworks como Laravel possuem essa funcionalidade de migration embutida.

Answer (score 8):

Boa resposta do @FReNeTiC. Gostaria, no entanto, de acrescentar algumas indicações de como fazer uma **auto-instalação**.

## Arquivo de configuração principal

Como o Wordpress, você vai precisar de uma configuração básica em arquivo que funcione independente do banco. Geralmente o arquivo vai conter as informações de acesso ao Banco de Dados, apontamentos para diretórios e linguagem principal.

Às vezes é possível que o arquivo seja criado automaticamente através de uma tela de instalação. Você faz uma tela com os dados necessários, o usuário completa o formulário e você grava o arquivo no local correto.

Mas, infelizmente, nem sempre isso é possível, pois em algumas hospedagens você não consegue gravar no sistema de arquivos e/ou não quer dar permissão de escrita para os scripts. Nesse caso, faça como o Wordpress: mostre o arquivo de configuração na tela e peça para o usuário criar um arquivo no servidor com o conteúdo exibido.

## Migrações de Banco de Dados

Quanto do banco de dados. Existem alguns frameworks de migrações de banco, como:

- [**Ruckusing Migrations**](https://github.com/ruckus/ruckusing-migrations): segue a filosofia do RoR (Ruby on Rails). As alterações no banco são feitas via código PHP. Suporta MySQL e PostgreSQL.
- [**Doctrine Migrations**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/introduction.html#): as alterações são especificadas em XML. O projeto Doctrine suporta MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle e outros, porém não sei se as migrações funcionam bem em todos eles.
- [**Phinx: Simple PHP Database Migrations**](https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx): fornece uma outra API para migrações via código PHP. Veja mais da documentação [aqui](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/intro.html). Suporta MySQL, PostgreSQL e SQLite.

Independente de escolher qualquer um desses, algum outro ou mesmo criar outra solução "na unha", é importante definir um método para que o seu banco de dados possa ser sempre atualizado para a versão mais atual quando seu sistema é executado.

## Considerações

Criar um sistema auto-instalável é algo que pode ser alcançado sem muitos problemas.

Por outro lado, gerenciar as atualizações no ciclo de vida do sistema pode ser complicado. Além disso, uma instalação com excelente usabilidade, intuitiva e amigável como a do Wordpress é algo que exige esforço.

Lembre-se de que o WP é um sistema já muito tradicional é que vem evoluindo ao longo dos anos. Eles conhecem os principais problemas que ocorrem em diferentes ambientes e possuem o *know-how* para fazer diversas verificações de ambiente antecipadamente, de forma a antecipar possíveis problemas. Então não espere um resultado tão bom de imediato.

Answer (score 3):

Eu noto que seu principal objetivo é ter uma qualidade melhor de software, sobretudo um alto grau de reuso no seu código. E claro, praticidade na entrega (deploy).

**Para melhorar suas aplicações PHP**, sugiro você utilizar e estudar algum framework. Assim você irá conhecer algumas arquiteturas, boas estratégias de OO, de reuso etc.. Veja esta pesquisa sobre os [frameworks em PHP mais promissores para 2014](http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-frameworks-2014/) (em inglês). Alguns destes frameworks poderão lhe dar esta funcionalidade de autoinstalar (ou pelo menos uma base).

**Ferramentas de deploy podem ajudar na entrega.** Muitas desses frameworks utilizam o que está no seu controle de versão (como o [git](http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)) pra empacotar e fazer entrega do seu código de maneira fantástica -- instalando a aplicação, fazendo migration, atualizando código etc. E o que você quiser que o usuário faça, Não é tão alto nível  é uma mão na roda pra empacotar a aplicação e "instalar" em algum lugar. Sei que o [TYPO3 Flow faz isto com o SURF](https://speakerdeck.com/hlubek/t3con12-deployment-with-surf), o [Symfony também faz](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html).

**Paralelamente, você poderia dar uma fuçada** no http://getcomposer.org/, um gerenciador de dependências para PHP. [Este tutorial](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/gerenciando-dependencias-com-o-composer/) dá uma boa visão. E há bons exemplos de pacotes em https://packagist.org/. Em todo caso, as respostas de @utluiz e @FReNeTiC são ótimas. Eu só faria isto com um framework -- o uso acelera a produtividade, qualidade e traz experiência. Claro, tudo tem um contraponto: em um ambiente de escala, às vezes um framework pode não tem a melhor performance para determinada solução.

Answer (score 3):

Do ponto de vista conceitual, você pode reduzir seu problema a dois pontos: **um arquivo do executável**, e outro **arquivo que contém os demais**, por exemplo, um arquivo zip.

Vou pressupor que vai usar PHP. Recomendaria fazer tudo em um só arquivo, até mesmo imagens, JS e CSS estarem neste arquivo, para evita

1. **Crie um arquivo único executável**, que, por questões de portabilidade, deve auto conter todos os Javascripts e CSSs da interface. Pode ser um script PHP, Perl, Shell, e afins.
2. **O arquivo executável deverá fazer pré-validações**, como checar se o servidor tem suporte a aplicação e checar se o arquivo compactado contendo a aplicação não está corrompido
3. **Sua aplicação deverá estar no arquivo compactado**. O arquivo executável deverá descompactar sua aplicação. Então você terá que optar por uma duas alternativas.

   1. Seu arquivo único executável deverá pedir instruções para instalar aplicação e  le mesmo. Ex.: útil quando se trata de um backup completo
   2. Seu arquivo único executável deverá passar para tela da sua aplicação que se encarregará de fazer a instalação na nova plataforma
4. Depois de finalizada instalação, você deverá remover o arquivo executável inicial e, preferencialmente, o arquivo compactado com a aplicação

Caso precise fazer algo relacionado a atualização após a aplicação ter sido instalada, será necessário integrar algo na aplicação que faça isso. Tanto Joomla quando Wordpress tem sistemas que funcionam exatamente fazendo isso.

Independente da aplicação, a parte de auto-update precisa ter algum tipo de integração mínima com a aplicação do cliente.

### Referencias

O item 3.1 é usado pelo Akeeba backup, uma das extensões mais famosas para o CMS Joomla https://www.akeebabackup.com.

Ademais, já trabalhei com algo semelhante a isso. É importante que você faça de forma que seja mais simples possível para o usuário, e que dê mensagens que façam ele entender que a culpa é do servidor que ele está ou de alguma coisa que ele vez (como arquivo corrompido).

### Pró-tip

Esse tipo de pergunta que você fez só vale a pena se for fazer em larga escala e seja economicamente interessante. Se não tiver certeza absoluta disso desde o início, faça da forma mais simples que imaginar e que exija o mínimo de conhecimento na aplicação que for usar, senão você vai ter um elefante branco. O modo como expliquei **é relativamente fácil de fazer**, **não exige permissões elevadas a funções que mexam com sistema** (logo podem ser usadas em qualquer hospedagem), e tem opção para **não obrigar saber muito sobre a aplicação que vai usar**.